# How To Manage Nested Navigation Flow Using Navigation Controller Using FragmentContainerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation, uinavigationcontroller

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2Vad.png)

1. load fragment pager in fragment landing and load fragment list one in view pager.
2. when click on square box load fragment archive in fragment landing.
3. when click on list fragments list item load fragment list detail fragment in fragment landing.

how to follow this flow with navigation controller?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not able to share code because I do not have permission to share code in any place.